limit iOS bluetooth connection to one device being used
Is there a way to limit bluetooth to one device connection so people cannot create unwanted connections on the iPhone in IOS. Some people just want the music.app and not kali linux connections...

Unless you are coding your own app this sounds like a question better suited in the Apple StackExchange

The problem is that bluetooth hardware 5.0 has seven different connections. At one earlier point I think since 4.2 hardware there can be up to three devices connected simultaneously and commands can override them and play from all three at once in sequence. They have easy code cracking softwares for them available by extension with kali linux, and other things for relatively intermediate pentesters, and people can just show others who are novices how to use them. I just don't like them bothering me during exercising it's disturbing. The blued and ioreg bother me.
He told me nothing I can do

No there isn't a way to achieve this either programmatically or through iOS. Through iOS, the only thing you can do is disable Bluetooth altogether or manually manage the Bluetooth connections yourself through Settings. Programmatically, this is not possible mainly for security and privacy reasons. Bluetooth is a system-wide functionality and therefore there is no way to have full control over it through the app's sandbox. Below are relevant links:-

Programmatically control Bluetooth in iOS
Enable/disable Bluetooth programmatically in CoreBlueooth
Disable Bluetooth hardware in iOS


"Most smartphones, TVs and computers and tablets manufactured since 2017 have Bluetooth 5.0 technology, which can connect up to seven different Bluetooth devices at once." -technology site
So there is no way to limit connections? Thank you for saving me hours of searching in a hopeless endeavor to stop serious noise pollution from unwanted connections.
